# try/except statements python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I include a restriction into this following loop with a minimal amount of coding? I'm using try and except but I can't figure out a way so that it will include only positive numbers. How can I achieve this?

```
dome_loop = 1
    while dome_loop == 1:
        dome = input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: ")
        try:
            dome = float(dome)
            break
        except ValueError :
                print("Please enter a value greater than 45!")
    tunnel_loop = 2
    while tunnel_loop == 2:
        tunnel = input("Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: ")
        try:
            tunnel = float(tunnel)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please enter in a positive number!")
```

This is my entire code:

```
import sys
import math


def iglooSelect(selection):
#Introduce selection
    if str(selection) == "budget" or selection == "1":
        print ("\nYou have selected (1) Budget ")
        x=45+15; y=45*25
    elif str(selection) == "superior" or selection == "2":
        print ("\nYou have selected (2) Superior")
        x=45+20; y=45*25
    elif str(selection) == "luxury" or selection == "3":
        print ("\nYou have selected (3) Luxury")
        x=45+25; y=30*20

    print ("NOTE tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
#Restrictions: Dome radius must be over 45.
    dome_loop = 1
    while dome_loop == 1:
        dome = input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: ")
        try:
            dome = float(dome)
            break
        except ValueError :
                print("Please enter a value greater than 45!")
    tunnel_loop = 2
    while tunnel_loop == 2:
        tunnel = input("Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: ")
        try:
            tunnel = float(tunnel)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please enter in a positive number!")



##    while tunnel!=(45):
##        tunnel = float(input("\nEnter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: "))
    tunnelarea = math.pi*tunnel*45 + math.pi*45**2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    domearea = 2*math.pi*dome**2 - 0.5*math.pi*x**2
    bricksrequired = (tunnelarea + domearea) /y
    print ("\nThis program will now calculate the number of bricks required", bricksrequired)
    print ("\nYou will require:",math.ceil(bricksrequired),"bricks")

    return None

def program(start):
    print ("Hello Eric the builder")
    print ("This program will calculate how mny bricks are required to build an igloo")
    # Start, print brick types
    start = input("Enter YES to start: ")
    if start == "yes":
        print ("(1) Budget - length: 45cm x height: 25cm x depth: 15cm")
        print ("(2) Superior - length: 35cm x height: 25cm x depth: 20cm")
        print ("(3) Luxury - length: 30cm x height: 20cm x depth: 25cm")
    else:
        print ("Error. This program will now exit")
        sys.exit()

    selection = input("Select your brick type: ")
    while selection not in [str(1),str(2),str(3)]:
        selection = input("You can only choose 1,2 or 3: ")

    iglooSelect(selection)
    restart = input("Enter YES to restart")
    return restart


    #Bricks rounded to nearest integer

start="yes"
while start == "yes":
    start=program(start)

print ("Error. This program will now exit")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
dome = -1
while dome <= 45:
    try:
        dome = float(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: "))
    except ValueError:
        dome = -1
    if dome <= 45:
        print ("Please enter a valid value greater than 45!")
```

This initially sets `dome` to an illegal value so that the loop is entered.

The loop then attempts to set it to something based on what the user enters but, if that wasn't a valid floating point number, forces it *back* to an illegal value. Entry of a valid floating point value like `17` is still considered illegal.

So the only way to exit the loop is to enter a valid floating point value that is also greater than forty-five.

A similar method can be used to ensure that `tunnel` is valid and non-negative:

```
tunnel = -1
while tunnel < 0:
    try:
        tunnel = float(input("Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: "))
    except ValueError:
        tunnel = -1
    if tunnel < 0:
        print ("Please enter a valid positive number!")
```

---

With those changes, your complete script now looks like:

```
import sys
import math

def iglooSelect(selection):
#Introduce selection
    if str(selection) == "budget" or selection == "1":
        print ("\nYou have selected (1) Budget ")
        x=45+15; y=45*25
    elif str(selection) == "superior" or selection == "2":
        print ("\nYou have selected (2) Superior")
        x=45+20; y=45*25
    elif str(selection) == "luxury" or selection == "3":
        print ("\nYou have selected (3) Luxury")
        x=45+25; y=30*20

    print ("NOTE tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")

#Restrictions: Dome radius must be over 45.
    dome = -1
    while dome <= 45:
        try:
            dome = float(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: "))
        except ValueError:
            dome = -1
        if dome <= 45:
            print ("Please enter a valid value greater than 45!")

    tunnel = -1
    while tunnel < 0:
        try:
            tunnel = float(input("Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: "))
        except ValueError:
            tunnel = -1
        if tunnel < 0:
            print ("Please enter a valid positive number!")

##    while tunnel!=(45):
##        tunnel = float(input("\nEnter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: "))
    tunnelarea = math.pi*tunnel*45 + math.pi*45**2
    domearea = 2*math.pi*dome**2 - 0.5*math.pi*x**2
    bricksrequired = (tunnelarea + domearea) /y
    print ("\nThis program will now calculate the number of bricks required", bricksrequired)
    print ("\nYou will require:",math.ceil(bricksrequired),"bricks")

    return None

def program(start):
    print ("Hello Eric the builder")
    print ("This program will calculate how mny bricks are required to build an igloo")
    # Start, print brick types
    start = input("Enter YES to start: ")
    if start == "yes":
        print ("(1) Budget - length: 45cm x height: 25cm x depth: 15cm")
        print ("(2) Superior - length: 35cm x height: 25cm x depth: 20cm")
        print ("(3) Luxury - length: 30cm x height: 20cm x depth: 25cm")
    else:
        print ("Error. This program will now exit")
        sys.exit()

    selection = input("Select your brick type: ")
    while selection not in [str(1),str(2),str(3)]:
        selection = input("You can only choose 1,2 or 3: ")

    iglooSelect(selection)
    restart = input("Enter YES to restart")
    return restart


    #Bricks rounded to nearest integer

start="yes"
while start == "yes":
    start=program(start)

print ("Error. This program will now exit")
sys.exit()
```

---

And here's a sample run to show it in action:

```
Hello Eric the builder
This program will calculate how mny bricks are required to build an igloo
Enter YES to start: yes
(1) Budget - length: 45cm x height: 25cm x depth: 15cm
(2) Superior - length: 35cm x height: 25cm x depth: 20cm
(3) Luxury - length: 30cm x height: 20cm x depth: 25cm
Select your brick type: 1

You have selected (1) Budget
NOTE tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)
Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: 40
Please enter a valid value greater than 45!
Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: 46
Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: hello
Please enter a valid positive number!
Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: -7
Please enter a valid positive number!
Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: 4

This program will now calculate the number of bricks required 12.948946786396329

You will require: 13 bricks
Enter YES to restart
Error. This program will now exit
```

Comment: @lichade: how about ... _what,_ exactly? :-)

Comment: I just posted it but I get this error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: I edited it but I get this error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @lichade, you need to check your code. I took your exact script and replaced the two input sections with my own and it works fine.

Comment: When I run the module, it only says  "Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: " . I used my code and replaced my 2 sections with yours.

Comment: If you're saying it prints out the prompt then exits, then you've made an error in entering the code. It works fine at my end. I assume you're using Python 3, yes?, since Python 2 won't like the `input()` call. All I can suggest is that you try again or post your new code somewhere where we can see it.

Comment: @lichade, I can only assume that's because you put them in the order I posted them. I tackled the `> 0` case first since that was the most logical for me. I've since re-arranged them to the correct order, as well as provided the complete script with them in the right order, so that should run as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
def is_float(in_str):    
    try:
        a_float = float(in_str)
        return True        
    except ValueError :    
        return False


while dome_loop == 1:
    dome = input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm: ")
    if not is_float(dome): 
        print("Not a number!")
        continue    

    dome = float(dome)

    if dome < 45:
        print("Please enter a value greater than 45!")
        continue

    break # everything OK, so we break out of the loop



tunnel_loop = 2

while tunnel_loop == 2:
    tunnel = input("Enter the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm: ")
    if not is_float(tunnel): 
        print("Not a number!")
        continue    

    tunnel = float(tunnel)

    if tunnel < 0:
        print("Please enter in a positive number!")
        continue

    break # everything OK, so we break out of the loop
```

The code defines generic helper function `is_float`. Once this test passes in the loops, you can start checking for any other conditions.

Comment: For some reason, I tried doing it but it only displays "Enter in your dome radius"